# What is the variable plotted on the y-axis on these Higgs exclusion graphs?

Tags: experimental-physics, particle-physics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Particle physics plots](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/13170/particle-physics-plots)

I have seen graphs like this in lots of talks by phenomenologists talking about the Higgs search (see for example [FIG 3 in this paper](http://prl.aps.org.proxy.uchicago.edu/abstract/PRL/v104/i6/e061802) or [this blog post](http://resonaances.blogspot.com/2010/07/higgs-still-at-large.html) or [slide 38 of this presentation](http://quark.phy.bnl.gov/~dawson/chicago1.pdf)).  I believe the y-axis is some sort of scaling, $R_{lim}$, applied to the expected Standard model signal, but I don't understand what is the source of this in the experiment and why it is different from $1$.  It appears to be some sort of a [Bayesian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_probability) calculation but I do not understand what exactly is being calculated.

[image]

Thanks!